# Group by id, but order by name

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this (created from joining different tables)

```
+------------+--------------+-------------+
| product_id | product_name | category_id |
+------------+--------------+-------------+
|     1      |    orange    |      3      |
|     1      |    orange    |      4      |
|     2      |    banana    |      2      |
|     3      |    apple     |      2      |
|     3      |    apple     |      3      |
|     3      |    apple     |      4      |
+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

I'd like it grouped together by ID, but sorted by name.

Like this

```
+------------+--------------+-------------+
| product_id | product_name | category_id |
+------------+--------------+-------------+
|     3      |    apple     |      2      |
|     3      |    apple     |      3      |
|     3      |    apple     |      4      |
|     2      |    banana    |      2      |
|     1      |    orange    |      3      |
|     1      |    orange    |      4      |
+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Is this possible? I tried using GROUP BY, but then it only keeps one row per product, so I can't see all the categories a product.

**edit: My query so far**

```
SELECT products.id as product_id, products.name as product_name, categories.id as category_id
FROM produkte
    LEFT JOIN prod_cat ON products.id = prod_cat.product_id
    JOIN categories ON prod_cat.category_id = categories.id
ORDER BY products.id
```

With "prod_cat" being the table that assigns categories to products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will order them by name then category id, giving the results as you have shown them.

```
SELECT products.id as product_id, products.name as product_name, categories.id as category_id
FROM produkte
    LEFT JOIN prod_cat ON products.id = prod_cat.product_id
    JOIN categories ON prod_cat.category_id = categories.id
ORDER BY product_name ASC, category_id ASC
```

I think you've misunderstood GROUP BY, but if you want to group them (reduce records to one where the field given in the GROUP BY clause matches), you can show the categories as a list using `GROUP_CONCAT(categories.id)` with `GROUP BY product_id`

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from products order by product_id desc, product_name asc;
```